# Java overriding abstract method using different param type

Tags: java, oop

I'm new to java, I have a dao class `Networks` which extends base dao class `MyDao`. In the future I will have numbers of dao classes which will extend `MyDao` my idea was to create an abstract methods in `MyDao` and specify superclass `MyModel` as argument type.
Example:

```
public class Network extends MyModel
{
}

abstract public class MyDao<T> {
    public abstract long save(T model);
    public abstract List<T> getAll();
}

public class Networks extends MyDao<Network> {
    @Override
    public long save(Network model)
    {
      /* do stuff */
    }

    @Override
    public List<Network> getAll()
    {
      /* do stuff */
    }     
}
```

I would like to know if this approach is viable in java or it's not, how similar task should be done ?

Comment: Yes, this is a valid method of implementing abstract methods in Java OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the way of using `Generic` in java. Explanation could be a generic `save` method is specific to concrete `Networks` class.